# Is there a maximum size for the persistence.mv.db?

Tags: corda

I wrote a cordapp which starts a schedulable flow every 10 minutes which records two transaction each time.
After a period of correct execution (neither exception, nor errors) the `persistence.mv.db` crashed due to the following error reported into the `persistence.trace.db`:

```
2018-04-27 03:22:00 database: flush
org.h2.message.DbException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Negative position -2904; p=123201377404004873, c=chunk:6d6cc,block:7fffffffffffffff,len:7fffffff,map:4b,max:9e8c40,next:7fffffffffffffff,pages:325,root:7fffffffffffffff,time:78ccfc8,version:6d6cc [1.4.194/6]" [50000-194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$1.uncaughtException(MVTableEngine.java:95)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.panic(MVStore.java:378)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1052)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.commitAndSave(MVStore.java:1039)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.beforeWrite(MVStore.java:2218)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.beforeWrite(MVMap.java:1051)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.put(MVMap.java:122)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.log(TransactionStore.java:282)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.log(TransactionStore.java:706)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.trySet(TransactionStore.java:1115)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.set(TransactionStore.java:1027)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.remove(TransactionStore.java:989)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.remove(MVSecondaryIndex.java:242)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.removeRow(MVTable.java:680)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:95)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1522)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1500)
    at net.corda.node.services.persistence.DBCheckpointStorage.removeCheckpoint(DBCheckpointStorage.kt:44)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.updateCheckpoint(StateMachineManager.kt:554)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.onExistingSessionMessage(StateMachineManager.kt:325)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.onSessionMessage(StateMachineManager.kt:296)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.access$onSessionMessage(StateMachineManager.kt:78)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager$resumeRestoredFibers$2.invoke(StateMachineManager.kt:263)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager$resumeRestoredFibers$2.invoke(StateMachineManager.kt:78)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient.callHandlers(NodeMessagingClient.kt:444)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient.access$callHandlers(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:429)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:84)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:75)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:421)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$fetchFrom$1.get(AffinityExecutor.kt:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Negative position -2904; p=123201377404004873, c=chunk:6d6cc,block:7fffffffffffffff,len:7fffffff,map:4b,max:9e8c40,next:7fffffffffffffff,pages:325,root:7fffffffffffffff,time:78ccfc8,version:6d6cc [1.4.194/6]" [50000-194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Negative position -2904; p=123201377404004873, c=chunk:6d6cc,block:7fffffffffffffff,len:7fffffff,map:4b,max:9e8c40,next:7fffffffffffffff,pages:325,root:7fffffffffffffff,time:78ccfc8,version:6d6cc [1.4.194/6]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:765)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPageChunkReferences(MVStore.java:1382)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1332)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1337)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1337)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1317)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.freeUnusedChunks(MVStore.java:1276)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNowTry(MVStore.java:1063)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1050)
    ... 52 more
2018-04-27 03:22:00 jdbc[634]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: File corrupted while reading record: "nio:/some/path/to/nodes/Node/persistence.mv.db". Possible solution: use the recovery tool; SQL statement:
delete from node_checkpoints where checkpoint_id=? [90030-194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:196)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.convertException(MVTable.java:904)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.remove(MVSecondaryIndex.java:248)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.removeRow(MVTable.java:680)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:95)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1522)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1500)
    at net.corda.node.services.persistence.DBCheckpointStorage.removeCheckpoint(DBCheckpointStorage.kt:44)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.updateCheckpoint(StateMachineManager.kt:554)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.onExistingSessionMessage(StateMachineManager.kt:325)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.onSessionMessage(StateMachineManager.kt:296)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager.access$onSessionMessage(StateMachineManager.kt:78)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager$resumeRestoredFibers$2.invoke(StateMachineManager.kt:263)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManager$resumeRestoredFibers$2.invoke(StateMachineManager.kt:78)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient.callHandlers(NodeMessagingClient.kt:444)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient.access$callHandlers(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:429)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:84)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:75)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:421)
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeMessagingClient$deliver$1.invoke(NodeMessagingClient.kt:76)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$fetchFrom$1.get(AffinityExecutor.kt:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Negative position -2904; p=123201377404004873, c=chunk:6d6cc,block:7fffffffffffffff,len:7fffffff,map:4b,max:9e8c40,next:7fffffffffffffff,pages:325,root:7fffffffffffffff,time:78ccfc8,version:6d6cc [1.4.194/6]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:765)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPageChunkReferences(MVStore.java:1382)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1332)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1337)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1337)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.collectReferencedChunks(MVStore.java:1317)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.freeUnusedChunks(MVStore.java:1276)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNowTry(MVStore.java:1063)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:1050)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.commitAndSave(MVStore.java:1039)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.beforeWrite(MVStore.java:2218)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.beforeWrite(MVMap.java:1051)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.put(MVMap.java:122)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.log(TransactionStore.java:282)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$Transaction.log(TransactionStore.java:706)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.trySet(TransactionStore.java:1115)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.set(TransactionStore.java:1027)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$TransactionMap.remove(TransactionStore.java:989)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.remove(MVSecondaryIndex.java:242)
... 42 more
```

And the size of `persistence.mv.db` exceeds 300MB.

Having Corda v2, how can I solve this error? Does the huge size of persistence.mv.db has something to do with it?

Is this statement (check the error above)

`delete from node_checkpoints where checkpoint_id=? [90030-194]`

useful to recover the DB whenever this error reoccurred? How can I use that?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the database file got corrupted. There is an H2 recovery tool that generates an sql script that can be replayed. You can find more information here: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#using_recover_tool.